# Force the same behaviour using Linq to nHibernate with Oracle as Linq to collections when comparing columns containing null

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, nhibernate, isnull

Suppose I have a Man class defined in nHibernate

```
public class Man
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string WifeName{get;set;}
   public string OldestChildName {get;set;}
}
```

with some instances:

```
Name   |WifeName   |OldestChildeName
-------+-----------+-----------------
Mike   |Penny      |Jenny
Bill   |           |Julia       
Tom    |Patricia   |Patricia
Peter  |           |
Bart   |Mellany    |
```

To select all persons where the oldest child name is the same as their wifes name

```
var names = 
  from m in men
  where m.WifeName == m.OldestChildName
  select m.Name
```

For Linq to collections this returns **Tom** and **Peter**.
But Linq to nHibernate to Oracle translates this to:

```
SELECT 
    m.name
FROM
    men m
WHERE 
    m.WifeName = m.OldestChildName;
```

which returns just **Tom**: in SQL comparisons to null evaluate to null, and null evaluates to false.

---

What I'd like to see generated is:

```
SELECT 
    m.name
FROM
    men m
WHERE 
    m.WifeName = m.OldestChildName
OR  (
        m.WifeName IS NULL
    AND m.OldestChildName IS NULL
    );
```

so in linq I need to type:

```
var names = 
  from m in men
  where m.WifeName == m.OldestChildName
    || (m.WifeName == null && m.OldestChildName == null)
  select m.Name
```

---

Is there a simple way to tell nHibernate to translate an equality comparison between two nullable colums, to a sql comparison and a null check?

In other words, is there a way to use the same linq query and get the same results regardless of if it's used for collections or databases?

All I could think of was building a pre-processor that parses the expression tree and modifies it to also emit the null checks. Has anybody already done this?

Comment: Your concept of "correct" is wrong. In SQL, a null is *not* equal to another null. One missing piece of information can't be considered equal to some other missing piece of information.

Comment: You're right, I changed the title. In SQL, null is interpreted as "unknown" and it is also unknown if unknown equals to unknown. In C# null is interpreted as no-value. No-value equals no-value.

I understand both points of view. In my daily work, most real-life problems map to the C# interpretation. So I'm looking for a way to make my queries behave this way.

Comment: That would be a very bad idea. The queries simply don't work that way. You'd get confused yourself *and* confuse maintainers of the code. Worst case, as the answer shows, you'd end up with extremely slow code without knowing why

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
Aside from the bad idea, what is the solution about the issue?
why does sql query cause stability problem?
I'm curious about your iddeas in this regard.

Comment: The query doesn't cause any stability problems. The problem is performance. In order to perform the comparison, the server has to calculate the results for all rows, then compare them. Without functions, the server can use indexed values to find and load only the relevant data pages. You can easily see the difference by checking the execution plan for both queries

Comment: linq != sql. So if I want to predict the result of men.Where(m.WifeName == m.FirstChildName), I don't really want to know the nature of men. Right now, I see lots of "AsEnumarable" and "ToList" in our code base, just because the properties of sql leak through into linq.

Comment: I was wondering if a filter (https://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters) might do it?

Answer (score -1):

The sql query you need.

```
select * from Stack
where COALESCE (wifeName,'')=COALESCE (OldestChildeName,'')
```

Output.
[image]

You need to use Nhibernate queryover for it.

```
var left = Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE",
NHibernateUtil.String,
Projections.Property<Stack>(pc => pc.OldestChildeName),
Projections.Constant(""));


var right = Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE",
NHibernateUtil.String,
Projections.Property<Stack>(pc => pc.WifeName),
Projections.Constant("") );

var restriction = Restrictions.EqProperty(left, right);

var dd = contex.Session<Stack>().QueryOver<Stack>().Where(restriction).List();
```

Output.

[image]

[image]

[ı suggest you lock](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html)

Comment: That will force the database server to scan the *entire* table. Applying functions to columns prevents the server from using indexes

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Just use a null check. There's nothing wrong with it. The problem is trying to force the semantics of one language over another